# Microsoft Bot framework with Wit.Ai for other language than English

Tags: botframework, wit.ai

Is it possible to use wit.ai with Microsoft Bot framework, as it supports more languages than LUIS for NLP?if so any sample demo or document available?

Comment: Can you please explain why you wouldn't just go with Wit.ai for your needs? Both frameworks allow for hooking up to the major messaging platform API's

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are still looking for this but will be helpful to anyone coming here.

There is a very nice npm module 
https://github.com/sebsylvester/botbuilder-wit that supports using wit.ai with Microsoft Bot Framework.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no Wit.ai support on the Bot Framework (for now).

Nervertheless, Microsoft plans to do it (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/144).
Since the Bot Framework is an open source project, you can do it by yourself but it's quite time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

I am at the early stages, but you can have a look at this.

https://github.com/q3blend/BotBuilder-Wit.ai

I hope it can help you